# Present ViewController over current context but the presenting View controller should take control of user interraction

Tags: ios, swift, modalviewcontroller, childviewcontroller

I am presenting a bottom banner over the current context:

```
        self.bottomViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        self.present(self.bottomViewController, animated: true, completion:{
            self.addChildViewController(self.bottomViewController)
            self.bottomViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        })
```

After presenting the modal view controller, I want the parent to still receive the touch events and takes control.

For some reasons I can't use the containment (add the view as subview and then animate the presentation)

Comment: Have you tried using delegates for this? Whatever action you receive on the`UIViewController` you are presenting, call the delegates inside that function you are using to receive actions and pass the appropriate information back.

Comment: @Rikh I have a complex presenting view controller with table view and buttons, so I want the presenting view controller to be the active view controller after presenting the modal view